# Sync Windows 8 calendar with iCal

Tags: windows-8, calendar, calendar.app

Is there any way to connect the Windows 8 calendar app to my iCloud.com calendar?

I see options to connect to the following types of accounts, but not an Apple one.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Hotmail Calendar and subscribe it to the iCloud Calendar. Go to the web interface of the Hotmail Calendar, menu Subscribe and paste the iCal URL. Afterwards just add the Hotmail account to the Windows 8 APP. It's not perfect but it avoids using another app.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible according to https://support.busymac.com/tickets/10998

> Google Calendar functions as a CalDAV server where all calendars are hosted. Each Mac (running BusyCal or OS X Calendar) and iOS device (running iOS Calendar app) functions as a CalDAV client and subscribes to the calendars hosted on Google Calendar. Once subscribed, calendars can be edited on any client and the changes will sync to the host and to all other clients.

and

> All calendars you wish to sync between your Macs, iOS devices, and other users, must be hosted on Google Calendar.
>
> - Local calendars will not sync with Google Calendar.
> - iCloud calendar subscriptions will not sync with Google Calendar.
> - LAN calendar subscriptions will not sync with Google Calendar.

There are no options in the Windows 8 Calendar app nor the iCloud.com website that allow syncing of calendars.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a iCloud account so this may not work, but if your iCloud calendar provides a calendar feed that you can subscribe to I may have found a workaround where if you create an outlook.com account and add that account to your Windows 8 calendar App and then add the calendar feed (ical, webcal, etc.) **using outlook.com** it will sync and show in the Windows 8 calendar app.  I was able to add several calendars to my account that I was unable to find a way to add using the Windows 8 calendar app itself.

Answer (score 1):

This windows 8 app can sync with icloud, yahoo and google calendar

http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/winpim-calendar/08436f52-dded-44a5-9508-c2b22235ac1d

Answer (score 0):

Viewing calendar details through 'windows live', going to share and selecting 'Links to "Calendar" with event details' doesn't seem to support formats for iCal / iCalendar, only;

- webcals
- calendar.ics

faq; widgets and api's for outlook --> iCalendar

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this solution by accident while I was trying to get an ical from my boss to sync with google so that I could sync it on my Lumia 1520 via google calendar (which doesn't work as well as this solution does.

Here is what has been working for me:

- Copy the webcal share link (webcal://p04-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/....)
- Go to https://icaltogcal.com/
- Use the site to generate a new URL
- copy the new URL
- Log into your Microsoft Account that is associated with the phone you are using.
- Go to the Calendar tab
- Click IMPORT (between New & share)
- Next page choose the SUBSCRIBE option
- Paste the new calendar URL you got from https://icaltogcal.com/
- Hit Subscribe
- Go to your Phone Settings>Email+accounts
- Sync your Microsoft Account

Your new calendar will instantly appear on your phone.
Not sure what the sync time is, still testing it out, but one thing is certain, I now have all the items on from the shared ical on my calendar in the color I want them. :)